# PFQuery not getting Object ID

Tags: xcode, core-data, swift, parse-platform

The code below checks Parse to see if an email address has been verified. I am able to retrieve the object ID from Core Data (I saved it in a previous view controller) but when it comes to `query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(userID)`, `userID` is for some reason `nil`. I get the error:

**Error: no results matched the query (Code: 101, Version: 1.6.0)**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class HomePage: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet var emailMessage: UILabel!

//var userID: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)

    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

        var res = results [0] as NSManagedObject

        var userID = res.valueForKey("userID") as String

        println (userID) //Correct ID is retrieved here


    var query = PFQuery(className:"User")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(userID) { //ID becomes nil
        (email: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            let checkEmail = email["emailVerified"] as Bool

            if (checkEmail != true)
            {
                self.emailMessage.hidden = false
            }

            else
            {
                self.emailMessage.hidden = true
            }

        }
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the way you're getting a PFQuery for the user. You should use the special user query:

```
var query = PFUser.query()
```

See [Users - Querying](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-querying/iOS), in the Parse docs.

Answer (score 2):

The `User` table (as well as all other parse-managed classes) in parse is prefixed by underscore, so you should fix this line:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
```

Comment: That's for my core data entity

Comment: Yeah just figured that out... fixing answer

Comment: However @fguchelaar's answer should work as well - and actually I think it's the best way

Comment: I will give his answer a try as soon as I can (I asked the question just as I was going for a break ;) )

Comment: thank you for you answer! You'r solution works just as well as fguchelaar's but I'm going to give them the check mark only because they answered first. But still, thanks!